Fast way of enumerating all child process and grandson of a given process on Windows
I am trying to enumerate all child process (and also their child process, so that's recursive) of a given process, just like how taskmgr is able to group all child process and their grandson processes.
I am currently using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot with Process32Next:

First save all the process entry to an array (so std::vector I am using)
recursively to find whether a process's th32ParentProcessID is equal to a pid I am currently looking, until there are no more child of this process (basically depth first search)

And this approach will massively increase the time complexity. Given how little CPU taskmgr consumes, I believe there is a better way.
UPDATE:
If I have to guess how taskmgr does this, I suppose it build up the process tree once, then it uses event to determine newly created/deleted process and update the tree.

For more details about enumerate process, you could refer to the Doc: Process Enumeration. You could try to use EnumProcesses enumerate all process.

@Jeaninez-MSFT That does not seem to solve the time complexity issue.

of course not use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot . use NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemProcessInformation

To the best of my knowledge there is no foundational API that gives you a process tree, so you'll have to iterate the process list and build a tree yourself.

at first - not use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot it has a monstrous implementation and performance. use NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, ..)
at second - you not need allocate any additional structures ( "std::vector I am using" ). possible do all with single allocation.
Simplified code for displaying a process tree:
void InitTreeView(_In_ HWND hwnd, 
                  _In_ TVINSERTSTRUCT* tvis, 
                  _In_ PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi, 
                  _In_ HANDLE UniqueProcessId)
{
    // entry inserted
    pspi->SpareLi3.LowPart = 1;

    // save current parent
    HTREEITEM hParent = tvis->hParent;

    tvis->item.lParam = hParent == TVI_ROOT ? -(LPARAM)UniqueProcessId : (LPARAM)pspi;

    tvis->hParent = TreeView_InsertItem(hwnd, tvis);

    // add childs
    while (ULONG NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset)
    {
        (PBYTE&)pspi += NextEntryOffset;

        if (pspi->InheritedFromUniqueProcessId == UniqueProcessId)
        {
            InitTreeView(hwnd, tvis, pspi, pspi->UniqueProcessId);
        }
    }

    // restore parent
    tvis->hParent = hParent;
}

void InitTreeView(_In_ HWND hwnd, _In_ PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi)
{
    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvis = { TVI_ROOT, TVI_LAST };

    tvis.item.mask = TVIF_PARAM|TVIF_TEXT|TVIF_STATE|TVIF_IMAGE|TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;
    tvis.item.state = TVIS_EXPANDED;
    tvis.item.stateMask = TVIS_EXPANDED;
    tvis.item.iImage = I_IMAGENONE;
    tvis.item.iSelectedImage = 0;

    tvis.item.pszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK;
    tvis.item.lParam = 0;

    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION _pspi = pspi;

    ULONG _NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset;

    ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;
    do 
    {
        (PBYTE&)pspi += NextEntryOffset;

        if (HANDLE UniqueProcessId = pspi->UniqueProcessId)
        {
            // entry yet not inserted
            if (!pspi->SpareLi3.LowPart)
            {
                _pspi->NextEntryOffset = RtlPointerToOffset(_pspi, pspi);
                InitTreeView(hwnd, &tvis, _pspi, pspi->InheritedFromUniqueProcessId);
            }
        }

    } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);

    _pspi->NextEntryOffset = _NextEntryOffset;
}

NTSTATUS BuildListOfProcesses(_Out_ PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION* ppspi)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    ULONG cb = 0x10000;

    do 
    {
        if (PVOID buf = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cb))
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                *ppspi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION)buf;
                return STATUS_SUCCESS;
            }

            LocalFree(buf);

            continue;
        }

        return STATUS_NO_MEMORY;

    } while (STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH == status);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

void Init(PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi)
{
    ULONG NextEntryOffset = 0;
    do 
    {
        (ULONG_PTR&)pspi += NextEntryOffset;

        // inserted
        pspi->SpareLi3.LowPart = 0;

    } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);
}

class ProWnd : public CSimpWnd
{
    enum { idTree = 1 };
    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION _pspi = 0;

    BOOL OnCreate(HWND hwnd)
    {
        if (0 <= BuildListOfProcesses(&_pspi))
        {
            Init(_pspi);

            RECT rc;
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
            if ( hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, WC_TREEVIEWW, 0, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|
                TVS_LINESATROOT|TVS_HASLINES|TVS_HASBUTTONS|TVS_DISABLEDRAGDROP|
                TVS_TRACKSELECT|TVS_EDITLABELS|TVS_INFOTIP,
                0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, hwnd, (HMENU)idTree, 0, 0))
            {
                InitTreeView(hwnd, _pspi);
                return 0;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    void OnDispInfo(TVITEMW* item)
    {
        if (item->mask & TVIF_TEXT)
        {
            if (ULONG cchTextMax = item->cchTextMax)
            {
                PWSTR pszText = item->pszText;

                union {
                    LPARAM lParam;
                    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
                };

                if (0 > (lParam = item->lParam))
                {
                    swprintf_s(pszText, cchTextMax, L"%x", (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)-lParam);
                }
                else if (0 < lParam)
                {
                    if (0 > swprintf_s(pszText, cchTextMax, L"%04x %wZ", (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR)pspi->UniqueProcessId, &pspi->ImageName))
                    {
                        __debugbreak();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    wcscpy_s(pszText, cchTextMax, L"ALL");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    virtual LRESULT WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
            return OnCreate(hwnd);

        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            if (_pspi)
            {
                LocalFree(_pspi);
            }
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            return TRUE;

        case WM_PAINT:
            if (BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps))
            {
                EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            }
            break;

        case WM_NOTIFY:
            switch (wParam)
            {
            case idTree:
                switch (reinterpret_cast<NMHDR*>(lParam)->code)
                {
                case TVN_GETDISPINFOW:
                    OnDispInfo(&reinterpret_cast<NMTVDISPINFO*>(lParam)->item);
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        }

        return __super::WindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};

void demo()
{
    if (NOERROR == CSimpWnd::Register())
    {
        ProWnd wnd;
        if (HWND hwnd = wnd.Create(0, L"Processes", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0))
        {
            ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
            MSG msg;
            while (0 < GetMessageW(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            }
        }
        CSimpWnd::Unregister();
    }
}



"you not need allocate any additional structures" - You don't, if you have someone else (like a treeview control) do the allocation. That's a left-pocket right-pocket calculation. If that reads like a win-win situation to you, you need a financial advisor.

@IInspectable First save all the process entry to an array (so std::vector I am using) this i mean. and for exactly got list of all child process and grandson of a given process we also not need do this - possible iterate list without temporary allocation. of course if want create plain array/vector after this - need allocate it and fill with pointers to processes. however i not give direct answer on question , how build vector of all child process and grandson of a given process. but instead show, how visualize this in tree.

@RbMm I see this algorithm is basically the same as mine, simply changed to another API. But I have difficulty getting it compiled (include files and libs, and my SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION seems have different fields than your code), can you share the complete project?

@szppeter no, this is not simply another api. Api which you use one of the most worst by implementation and have terrible performance. Usual win32 api only small shell over nt api call, but not in this case. About how compile and link, this is already different questions. But i somehow managed do this. So it possible
